# Search Twitter for pictures using API

Tags: javascript, search, rest, twitter, image

I'm searching for a way to get tweets which have a link to a picture residing in them. I would like to make a stream of pictures posted on Twitter using a certain hash-tag. Yet i've found no way to detect if tweets contain pictures and how to get those pictures from the different picture providers like twitpic, yfrog, instagram, lockerz, etc.

If anyone here has some knowledge that could give me a kickstart, it would be very welcome.

Comment: According to [this](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1513) it may be difficult to find the links to images with the REST API at this time. Since most images are wrapped in t.co links, you'd have to parse them out of the text and then check to see if they are an image, but in the future, the REST Api will provide the URL entities.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.twicsy.com/   has services that may help you, take a look.

It won't work for our needs, because they don't permit automated crawling, only searches triggered by an end user.   But take a look.

Answer (score 0):

there's a wordpress plugin for this. have a look at:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ep-hashimage/

Answer (score 0):

check this:
http://blog.embed.ly/findpitcom-building-a-twitter-image-search-wi